# print() em loop com time.sleep() só exibe as mensagens depois

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um código como se fosse uma máquina, então eu decidi colocar isso para tentar imitar um som:

```
 while(aux>0):
    print("Bzz..",end="")
    aux-=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

A ideia era de que printrasse "Bzz.. Bzz.. Bzz" na mesma linha com um intervalo de 1 seg para cada um aparecer, porem todos aparecem juntos no fim dos 3 segs, por que isso acontece e como eu posso deixar do jeito que eu pensei?

Comment: `print("Bzz..", end="", flush=True)`  seria dessa forma  o **flush=True**   força o esvaziamento do buffer

Comment: O buffer sera determinado pelo parâmetro file= do print(), na ausencia desse parametro o sys.stdout sera usado, então a fora que o buffer trabalha poderá variar de terminal para terminal, em um terminal que testei funcionou perfeitamente, no cmd do Windows ja tive o mesmo problema que o seu, usar o flush=True resolvera de forma forcada, como ja foi dito.

Comment: Então @Danizavtz, a parada é : quando   coloca o "end=" " depois do "Bzz..",   tá dando uma folguinha pro "Bzz.." antes de imprimir a próxima string. É tipo dar um tempinho pro "Bzz.." respirar, sabe? Mas aí, se   não limpa o buffer de saída antes de imprimir a próxima string, as strings vão ficar todas entupidas lá, como se fossem geladeira cheia de cerveja da pra imaginar? É por isso que o uso o flush=True, pra dar uma desobstruída nesse negócio. É como se fosse uma limpeza.

Comment: @stack.cardoso entendi, deu pra pegar a ideia dps que executei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O buffer no `print()` geralmente é determinado pelo parâmetro `file=`, conforme:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)
```

Se for `file=None` ou se não for definido (o caso do seu código) será usado [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)

Dependendo do terminal você pode obter a saída desejada de imediato ou então só ao final mesmo, por exemplo, em um terminal que usei não precisei usar o `flush=True`, já no cmd do Windows foi usado o buffer (ocasionando o problema que citou na pergunta).

Note que você pode usar `flush=` como True, então fluxo será liberado à força, o que provavelmente resolve a sua necessidade **mas isso é só a partir do Python 3.3**, antes disso tinha que controlar de outras formas, coisas como reabrir o [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) controlando:

```py
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

Ou setar a variável de ambiente [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) ou então executar o python com a flag `-u`, assim:

```
python -u exemplo.py
```

De forma semelhante ao `print(..., flush=True)`, você pode controlar o *flush* do [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) com o método `.flush()`

Exemplo com `sys.stdout.write`

```py
import time, sys

x = 0

while x < 5:
    sys.stdout.write('Bzz.. ')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    x += 1
```

Exemplo com `print` (já que o `file=` implícito é o próprio [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)):

```py
import time, sys

x = 0

while x < 5:
    print('Bzz.. ', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    x += 1
```